# Retrieve value from db which is stored in json encode format - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, mysql-workbench

[image]

Friends from the above image I have saved the values of category_id in json_encode format directly and for processing , I'm retrieving the values but i'm not getting the result as expected . My requirement is I need to retrieve the value of rss_url_id which belongs to category_id 1 , it should return rss_url_id 2 .

I use the query

```
SELECT rss_url_id FROM rss_url  WHERE `status` = 0 AND REPLACE( REPLACE(`category_id`,'[', '' ) , ']', '' ) LIKE '%1%'
```

But this query returns the both the result as in the first row it contains value 10 as i'm using like %1% it returns both the result, is there is any alternate query to return only the 2nd row . if i give the value as 1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT rss_url_id FROM rss_url  WHERE `status` = 0 AND `category_id` LIKE '%"1"%'
```

Keep your category_id (to be searched) in double quotes